# Left sidebar category navigation disappearing on last level category pages in Magento

Tags: magento, navigation, anchor, categories, sidebar

On the lowest category levels, my sidebar is disappearing in Magento. Anchor is set to no for all my categories. Ultimately I want to display all main categories on sidebar (obviously on every product page) and the sub categories when inside a main category.

Not sure what the issue is.  Pretty much base magento code with some style changes.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('Products') ?></h2>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <h2 class="red">Holiday</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Christmas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Halloween</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thanksgiving</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Easter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4th of July</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Valentine's Day</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Mary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Licensing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Custom Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
<?php endif; ?>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are disappearing on your lowest categories because your code is using:

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
```

If your current category (the category are you currently viewing) has no child categories, the block will not display any categories (because `getCurrentChildCategories()` returns the child categories of the **current** category).

The left categories will behave differently depending on whether the Is Anchor is set to Yes or No.

1. Category is set to `Is Anchor: Yes`
   -The left categories will function as a filter, instead of a direct navigation link.  When you click on a category on the left, you will remain in the same category you were viewing, however the results on the page will be filtered to the selected category.
2. Category is set to `Is Anchor: No`
   -The left categories will function as a menu.  When a category is selected, the user will be taken to that actual category page.  If the category page they navigate to has no subcategories, no categories will appear on the left.

So in your case, you can set your upper level categories to `Is Anchor: Yes` and the lowest categories will act as filters instead of menu links.

If you want people to navigate to the lowest level subcategories, you will have to modify the functions the template uses to pull the categories from the parent category.  There are several articles on StackOverflow already detailing how to do this.

Comment: where I can find this file ? where to change this ? @Axel